# Input value of cookie

Tags: javascript, jquery, cookies

I want to apologize in advance if this is a repeat question.  I want to be able to input the value of a previous page using cookies with JQuery.

I know how to set/get/remove but I've never tried to use the values for input fields.

Can someone give guidance/example on how to accomplish this?

JQuery:

```
//plug-in//
<script src="/path/to/jquery.cookie.js"></script>

<script>
//set and expire form 1//

$(document).ready(function(){
var date = new Date();
var minutes = 5;
date.setTime(date.getTime() + (minutes * 60 * 1000));
$.cookie('name1', 'value1', { expires: date, path: '/' });
$.cookie('name2', 'value2', { expires: date, path: '/' });
$.cookie('name3', 'value3', { expires: date, path: '/' });
$.cookie('name4', 'value4', { expires: date, path: '/' });
});

</script>

<script>
//get form 2//

$(document).ready(function(){
$.cookie('name1');
$.cookie('name2');
$.cookie('name3');
$.cookie('name4');

//remove form 2//
$.cookie('name1', null);
$.cookie('name2', null);
$.cookie('name3', null);
$.cookie('name4', null);
});

</script>
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

When you read a cookie value, in order for that value to be useful, you do have to assign it to a variable. Then you can use the variable to manipulate an input element in the current page:

```
//page 2 
$(document).ready(function(){
    var name1 = $.cookie('name1');
    $('input[name=page1_name1]').val( name1 );
});
```

Where the input element in page 2 is:

```
<input type="text" name="page1_name1"/>
```

Comment: Thank you and sorry for the late reply.

Comment: No problem. Glad I could be of help.